# Scraping data from a complex graph

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

For a personal project, I want to scrape data from this URL:
https://evemarketer.com/types/2410/history

I am not used to scrape data and I don't know how to do it .

I have written a bunch of code, but I don't know how to specify how data should be organised.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import time


url ="https://evemarketer.com/types/2410/history"
x = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

I want to have all the variables organised in a column with the time.

Do you know how I could achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what you want to scrape from this website ? can you show any sample output

Answer (score 1):

> Go to Chrome developer mode and navigate to Network Tab and reload
> your website now you will find many URL will be loading
>
> As your site data is generated dynamically go to XHR tab and you will
> find lots of URL and take appropraite URL by preview the content of
> that URL

Code:

I have filter out only `2021` data

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res=requests.get("https://esi.evetech.net/v1/markets/10000002/history/?type_id=2410")
lst=[]
main_data=res.json()
for i in range(len(main_data)):
    if main_data[i]['date']>='2021-01-01':
        lst.append(main_data[i])
```

Now load `lst` to `pandas` DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Output:

```
    average     date        highest     lowest  order_count volume
0   1343000.0   2021-01-01  1349000.0   1333000.0   243 1406
1   1322000.0   2021-01-02  1322000.0   1322000.0   246 1317
2   1314000.0   2021-01-03  1317000.0   1044000.0   299 1460
3   1298000.0   2021-01-04  1300000.0   1297000.0   244 1979
4   1330000.0   2021-01-05  1350000.0   1298000.0   280 2098
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
311 1392000.0   2021-11-08  1396000.0   1326000.0   250 1543
312 1389000.0   2021-11-09  1394000.0   1302000.0   313 1618
313 1387000.0   2021-11-10  1390000.0   1385000.0   264 1761
314 1490000.0   2021-11-11  1501000.0   1390000.0   227 2417
315 1465000.0   2021-11-12  1478000.0   1449000.0   225 1414
316 rows × 6 columns
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded dynamically by javascript. So I use selenium and grab table data using pandas as follows:

Code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

driver.get("https://evemarketer.com/types/2410/histor")
time.sleep(3)
table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table').get_attribute('outerHTML')

df = pd.read_html(table)[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          Region  Quantity  ...       Expires In Received At
0          Curse        11  ...   89d 7h 41m 23s      1m ago
1          Curse        21  ...     63d 6h 8m 2s      1m ago
2          Curse         6  ...  54d 15h 53m 22s      1m ago
3          Curse        13  ...   89d 22h 3m 35s     56m ago
4          Stain         5  ...   72d 6h 24m 26s     54s ago
..           ...       ...  ...              ...         ...
396  Sinq Laison         1  ...   6d 10h 56m 47s      2m ago
397  Sinq Laison         1  ...   6d 10h 56m 33s      2m ago
398  Sinq Laison         1  ...   6d 10h 56m 42s      2m ago
399  Sinq Laison         1  ...   6d 10h 56m 29s      2m ago
400   Metropolis         1  ...  85d 11h 19m 27s      3m ago

[401 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: thank very much ^^ Could you explain me how it work please ?